# Redirect Loop during the language detection

Tags: php, http, redirect, infinite-loop

People,

I'm working on a function based on the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE and when I tested, the browser displays a redirection loop. I investigated all the solution provided in other posts but doesn't work

**Updated:  I tried to do this first using the httaccess detecting the language and redirecting to the correct page using the proper page and lang variables but I found the same issue. The problem is that I used two variables: page ( to determine in which page is the user ) and lang ( proper language depending on the spoken language of the user ). But the first time when the user arrives to the site: both variables are null so the purpose of this is detect the browser language of the user and then redirect it to the proper url, in my case..... index.php?page=index&lang=en for instance...**

I did this:

```
**init.php**

$supportedLangs = array (
    'en-GB',
    'en-US',
    'es-ES',
    'es-AR'
 );

 $languages = explode ( ',', $_SERVER ['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] );

 detectBrowserLanguage($languages,$supportedLangs);



 **functions.php**


 function detectBrowserLanguage($languages,$supportedLangs) {

foreach ( $languages as $lang ) {
    if (in_array ( $lang, $supportedLangs )) {

            // Set the page locale to the first supported language found
         switch ($lang) {
        case 'es-ES' :
        header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=es", TRUE, 301 );
        exit ();
        break;

        case 'en-US' :
        header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=en", TRUE, 301 );
        exit ();
        break;

        case 'en-GB' :
        header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=en", TRUE, 301 );
        exit ();
        break;

        default :
        header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=es", TRUE, 301 );
        exit ();
        break;
        }
    }
    }
   }
```

Comment: In your code there is no way to break out of the loop. Suppose if you have you have detected language `en` and redirected to `index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=en`, on the redirected page it will again detect language `en` adn do redirect again to `index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=en` (infinite loop)

Comment: Isn't it a better approach to include the relevant code according to the preferred language of the browser instead of redirecting with `lang=`. This way you know which is the preferred language when the user first visits the page. (no redirection = better, user friendly, faster website)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling detectBrowserLanguage from your index.php page.  Make sure the function is not called when the Lang parameter is passed in the URL.

You can check that with

```
isset($_GET['lang'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a method to break out of the loop if the page is already in the detected language. Note: refer to my comment on your question.

```
$supportedLangs = array (
    'en-GB',
    'en-US',
    'es-ES',
    'es-AR'
 );

 $languages = explode ( ',', $_SERVER ['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] );
 $currentLanguage='';
 if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
      $currentLanguage=$_GET['lang'];
 }
 detectBrowserLanguage($languages,$supportedLangs, currentLanguage);
```

**Function**

```
function detectBrowserLanguage($languages,$supportedLangs, $currentLanguage) {
    
    foreach ( $languages as $lang ) {
        if ($lang == $currentLanguage){
            return; //If the page is already redirected just return.
        }elseif (in_array ( $lang, $supportedLangs )) {
    
                // Set the page locale to the first supported language found
             switch ($lang) {
            case 'es-ES' :
            header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=es", TRUE, 301 );
            exit ();
            break;
    
            case 'en-US' :
            header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=en", TRUE, 301 );
            exit ();
            break;
    
            case 'en-GB' :
            header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=en", TRUE, 301 );
            exit ();
            break;
    
            default :
            header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=es", TRUE, 301 );
            exit ();
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You can do this much easily with [http_negotiate_language](https://www.php.net/http_negotiate_language). This is just a guide on how to do it. I have not tested this (just typed in here)

```
function detectBrowserLanguage($supportedLangs, $currentLanguage) {
    $negotiated_language = http_negotiate_language($supportedLangs);
    if ($currentLanguage != $negotiated_language){
        switch ($negotiated_language) {
            case 'es-ES' :
            header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=es", TRUE, 301 );
            exit ();
            break;
    
            case 'en-US' :
            header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=en", TRUE, 301 );
            exit ();
            break;
    
            case 'en-GB' :
            header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=en", TRUE, 301 );
            exit ();
            break;
    
            default :
            header ( "Location: index.php?pagina=inicio&lang=es", TRUE, 301 );
            exit ();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Reference:

1. [W3 Accept-Language
   RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4)
2. [Language Tags](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.10)

Comment: I try this but nothing change. During the navigation of the site I working with the page and the lang in the URL so perhaps there is the problem

Comment: Can you check what is in `$languages` and `$_GET['lang']`. Also note `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` don't need to send in `en-EN` format check http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4

Comment: I should set the pagina and lang values as empty and if the browser detects this assign the correct value to them depend of the browser language configuration